# Qt C++ Timer inside a QThread and send data from QThread to GUI Thread

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread, qtimer

I created a timer in a thread and in this timer char value counts from 0 to 10.
I want to display this char value on the GUI. I do not get any error but the GUI freeze when I started.

Can you help me on where I am doing wrong please?

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mythread.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    MyThread *mThread;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void onNumberChanged(char);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mThread = new MyThread(this);
    connect(mThread,SIGNAL(NumberChanged(char)), this, SLOT(onNumberChanged(char)));
    mThread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onNumberChanged(char Number)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(Number));
}
```

mythread.h

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void NumberChanged(char);

public slots:
    void update();

private:
    QTimer *timer;

};
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QtCore>

char i=45;
QString mystr = "mytext";

MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    timer= new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(10);
}

void MyThread::update()
{
    for( i = 0; i<10; i++){
    emit NumberChanged(i);
    this->msleep(500);
    }
    if (i>0)
        i=0;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
}
```

Comment: `MyThread` has a `QTimer` set to call `update()` every 10 milliseconds, but within `update()` you call `msleep(500)` 10 times, meaning that `update()` will take more than 5 seconds to return.  One of those things has got to go; if you want to call `update()` often, it need to return quickly.

Comment: Please read about threads and thread affinity in Qt. Your code clearly shows you are using trial and error method to learn about threads. While this approach may work with some other areas of Qt, it definitely does not work with threads... The reason is that threads may very often seem to work correctly even if they do not. With threads you need to understand the logic of the mechanism. You need to understand that the thread object "lives" in the main GUI thread but its `run()` method is executed in the thread itself. Btw. why your `run()` is empty? It does not make any sense.

Comment: Btw. do not use old style of connections with `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros any more. It has been obsolete for very very long time. And I bet you do not use Qt4, or do you?

Comment: Also do not ever use global variables... (unless you really have to)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Okay, if I remove `msleep(500)`, everything is fine?
@V.K. Thank you I will read it. I initialized, connect and started timer in `run()`, it still not works. I am using Qt 5. I do not know what to use instead of `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` that is why I used. What can I use instead?

Comment: you can use "connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout ,this ,&MyThread::update);" insted of " connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));"

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your timer in the run() function, not in the constructor.
because the constructor is called in GUI thread and each object that is created in this function is in GUI thread. or you can call moveToThread for your timer to move to your thread.

Comment: Okay I see, you are right. I created, and started the timer in the run() function. But it still does not works.

Comment: please check the update() method was called in the new thread. add connection type at the end of your connect (Qt::queueConnection) and check main thread was different with update() method caller with QThread::currentThreadId().

Comment: of course, you need to add connection type (Qt::queueConnection)to both of your connect signal slot in your code.